# Minimum of Poisson processes with constraints

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I am taking a Stochastic Processes class and i have a homework assignment that goes like this:

**Let X and Y be two homogenous poisson processes with rate 1 and 2 respectively. What is the distribution of $$T=\min(t: X(t)+Y(t)=1)$$**

**What have i tried so far?** I know that $X(t)+Y(t)$ is a Poisson process with rate function $\lambda$ given by $$\lambda(t)=\lambda_{1}(t)+\lambda_{2}(t)$$

Which in our case results in $\lambda = 3$.
Moreover, i know that if $Z=\min \left\{X, Y\right\}$, then $P\left(X<Y\right)=\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}}$, we did that during class. Right now i am trying to do some sort of conditioning to obtain the distribution. How can i proceed?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: For the result on the superimposed process we must assume that $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are independent (which you probably just forgot to include when writing the question).

Comment: Anyway, you are overthinking this. $T$ is just the time of the first arrival in a Poisson process, whose distribution is well-known.

Comment: The problem was that inpendence was not assumed, so i thought it was some kind of a challenge question or something similar. However, i asked the teacher and he told me he forgot to write that in the problem. It is all good now!!